# Can I receive SMS from a bluetooth connected phone?

Tags: sms, bluetooth, windows-mobile

I have a Windows Phone 7.5 phone and recently got an used (non-returnable) Android 4.4 phone. I love the Android experience but the phone is not on the right carrier. Is there a way to use bluetooth to forward SMS to the Android phone or will I just need a new one? If it took phone calls too that'd be sweet but not near as urgent.

Comment: You would need to carry both phones at all times and keep both phones charged.  With that said, I do not know of a method of doing what you want to do.

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward I'm doing that anyway in order to use the Android phone at all. I'm not sure there is a solution for what I want. I think it's possible though so I might try and make one myself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows phone so I can't speak to this working but you may be able to do this with [Pushile](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/pushile/9nblggh16hmb) for Windows Phone and [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/apps) for Android.

As long as both devices have connectivity it should work. You may even be able to reply from your Android device. This all depends on Pushile allowing for notification forwarding. It's a setting you'll have to enable on both devices.

Note: Pushile is an independent app not developed by Pushbullet. There is another Windows Phone Pushbullet 3rd party app called Pushpin which could also be worth a  look. There is a link at the bottom of the Pushbullet page linked above.